# Remove all whitespaces in URL/Email

Tags: python, regex, removing-whitespace

I'd like to remove all whitespaces in URLs / Email addresses. The addresses are in a "normal" string, like: `"Today the weather is fine. Tomorrow, we'll see. More information: www.weather .com or info @weather.com"`

I'm looking for a good regex (using the `re` module of Python), but my versions can't handle all cases

```
re.sub(u'(www)([ .])([a-zA-Z\-]+)([ .])([a-z]+)', '\\1.\\3.\\5')
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Couldn't you just use `replace`? `"https://www . some-example.c o m".replace(' ', '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression for url just require a little fixing. The regex expression for email can also be inherited from url expression.

```
>>> #EXPRESSIONS:
>>> url = "(www)+([ .])+([a-zA-Z\-]+)+([ .])+([a-z]+)"
>>> ema = "([a-zA-Z]+)+([ +@]+)+([a-zA-Z\-]+.com)"
>>> 
>>> #IMPORTINGS:
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> #YOUR DATA:
>>> string = "Today the weather is fine. Tomorrow, we'll see. More information: www.weather .com or info @weather.com"
>>> 
>>> #Scraping Data
>>> "".join(re.findall(url,string)[0])
'www.weather.com'
>>> "".join(re.findall(ema,string)[0]).replace(" ","")
'info@weather.com'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped a lot! One last question: What regex could I use if i want to add a space to "/" in a normal text, but not in a URL. Example: "Hello ladies/gentleman. You can find more information on www.skynews.com/today/act ." --> "Hello ladies / gentleman. You can find more information on www.skynews.com/today/act ."

Comment: @StMan You can accept my answer. If your URL don't contain spaces then this will work: `(www.)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w]*)`